# Is there other option to check if a table is in a SQl connection , Im trying to use dialect.has_table

Tags: python, sql, web-scraping, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from .conf import DB_CONNECTION_STR

conn = create_engine(DB_CONNECTION_STR)

def verify_table_exists(table_name):
    return conn.dialect.has_table(conn, table_name)
```

Im getting this error :

> AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'exec_driver_sql'

Comment: what is your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays the preferred method for performing such reflection is to use `inspect`:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

insp = sa.inspect(engine)
print(insp.has_table("team"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gord Thompson

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use 'inspect' in sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from .conf import DB_CONNECTION_STR

conn = create_engine(DB_CONNECTION_STR)

def verify_table_exists(table_name):
    return inspect(conn).has_table(table_name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much eshirvana